# Derivatives of Matrices in Lagrangian and LASSO Optimization with Shrinkage Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, regularization

The goal is to write a program that solves for ***x*** in

$$\textbf{min}\quad \|A\textbf{x}-\textbf{b}\|_1+\sigma \|\bf x \|_1$$
for $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. We assume that ${m}<{n}$ and ${\sigma}>{0}$. This optimization problem can also be reformulated as an LP.

The program must be an ADMM (alternating direction method of multipliers) on the variables
$$
{\bf u}={A}{\bf x}-{\bf b},\quad \quad {\bf v}=\sigma{\bf x}
$$

Which leads to
$$
\bf min \quad \|{\bf u}\|_{1}+\|v\|_{1} \\
s.t.\quad \binom{\textit{A}}{\sigma I}x-\binom{u}{v}=\binom{b}{0}
$$
So I set up me wee little **Augmented Lagrangian**
$$
\mathcal{L}_{\rho}({\bf x,u,v,\nu})
=
{\bf \|u\|_{1}+\|v\|_{1}   }
+\Lambda^\top \left(\binom{\textit{A}}{\sigma I}{\bf  x-\binom{u}{v}-\binom{b}{0} }\right)
+
\frac{\rho}{2}\left\|\binom{\textit{A}}{\sigma I}{\bf  x-\binom{u}{v}-\binom{b}{0} 
 }\right\|_{2}^{2}
$$

***Question 1 & 2***

I know how to do $\displaystyle\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \bf x}$, but what is  $\displaystyle\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \bf u}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \bf v}$?

***Question 3***

These equations were given
$${\bf x}^{({k}+{1})}
=
\left(
{A}^\top {A}+{\tau}^{2 }{I}
\right)^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
{A}\\{\tau}{I}
\end{pmatrix}^\top 
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
{\bf u}\\{\bf v}
\end{pmatrix}
^{({k})}
+\begin{pmatrix}
{\bf b}\\{\bf 0}
\end{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{\rho}{\Lambda}^{({k})}
\right)$$

what is $\Lambda^{(0)}$?

***Question 4***
$${\Lambda}^{({k}+{1})}
=
{\Lambda}^{({k})}
+
\frac{1}{\rho}
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}{A}\\{\tau}{I}\end{pmatrix} {\bf x}^{({k}+{1})}-\begin{pmatrix}{\bf u}\\{\bf v} \end{pmatrix}^{({k}+{1})}-\begin{pmatrix}{\bf b}\\{\bf 0} \end{pmatrix}
\right)$$
where did this equation come from?

***Question 5***

How do you find $\displaystyle\binom{\bf u}{\bf v}^{k+1}$? The instructions are to use a `skrinkage operator on` $\displaystyle\binom{\bf u}{\bf v}$. What is that?!!!!

I have been reading the textbook for days. Epically stumped on this

Thanks,

Jason

Undergraduate Math

University of California, Berkeley

Comment: What textbook have you been reading?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Gilbert Strang- Linear Algebra and Learning from Data 2019